# Hiding console using --noconsole command but encountering error

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made and exe file using pyinstaller and when I m trying to hide the console using `--noconsole` or `-w` then this command runs perfectly
`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py`
But after running the **.exe** file a error dialog appears with title *Fatal error!* With message **main.exe returned -1**